# Proving Convergence of a limit related to Cross-Spectrum Estimation

Tags: window-functions, math, spectrum-estimation

Proving asymptotic covariance of Cross-Spectrum Estimation I came across this mathematical problem:

Consider two constants $M,L$ such that  $M\to \infty, L \to \infty \hbox{ and } \frac{L}{M} \to 0$, And $\ell,s,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ $\nu_1,\nu_1 \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \lim_{M\to +\infty} \left\{\frac{1}{L}\sum_{\ell=-M}^{M} U_M(r,\ell,s) w\left(\frac{\ell+s}{L}\right)\  w\left(\frac{\ell}{L}\right) e^{-2\pi i\ell(\nu_1-\nu_2)}\right\}$$

where  $r$, $s$ are constants and:

$$ U_M(r,\ell,s)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &  r<-M+\ell+s\\
1-\frac{\ell+s+r}{M}& -M+\ell+s\leq r \leq 0 \\ 
1-\frac{\ell+s}{M}& 0 < r \leq s\\ 
1-\frac{\ell+r}{M}& s<r \leq M-\ell\\
0 &  r>M-\ell 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
And $w(x)$ is a function which is even, bounded,  square-integrable and such that $w(0)=1$.

It has been proven [1] that this limit exists and it is equal to  0 for $\nu_1\neq\nu_2$ and :
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w^2(x)dx $$
for $\nu_1=\nu_2$. 
I am trying to prove that replacing in the limit $U_M(r,\ell,s)$ by

$$V_M(r)= \left(1-\frac{|r|}{M}\right)$$

Produces the same result but I don't have the background to understand the mentioned proof, is there a simple way to prove this claim? I am only interested in the case of $V_M(r)$.

[1] Hannan, E. J. *Multiple time series*, vol. 38. John Wiley & Sons, 2009. Proof of Theorem 9 chapter V, page 314.

Comment: Would math.SE be a better fit for this question? What is the conexion to signal processing?

Comment: Ya, but Ted Hannan always thought of himself as a statistician, so Math.SE might be better. Or crossvalidated.SE. Let me know and I can migrate it.

Comment: I'm studiying asymptotic covariance for a specific Blackman-Tukey type correlogram. Here, w(x) is the tappering window. Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: The triangle window was kind of apparent. Some notations in your question are uneven, and don't help the reading (like arguments to $U_M$), and the constants that tend to infinity, well. I believe you could further simplify the question to forster answers

Comment: The definition of function U is problematic. If r and s are fixed integers, then according to the second piece-wise definition condition r must be less than zero (hence it's a negative number) but then according to the third and fifth definitions, r is greater than zero ? The same also happens for the s variable. The conditions to be satisfied by those fixed integers seem to be inconsistent...

Answer (score 1):

A first thing to try is to reduce the unwanted variables. What happens if you set  $\ell=s=0$?

$$ U_M(r,0,0)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &  r<-M\\
1-\frac{r}{M}& -M\leq r \leq 0 \\ 
1-\frac{0}{M}& 0 < r \leq 0\\ 
1-\frac{r}{M}& 0<r \leq M\\
0 &  r>M 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Luckily, this definition seems to fit with $V_M$, since the third inequality never happens. So your $V_M(r)$ is just a special case. Nothing more to do.

Comment: The definition of function *U* is problematic. If *r* and *s* are fixed integers, then according to the second piece-wise definition condition *r* must be less than zero (hence it's a negative number) but then according to the third and fifth definitions,  **r** is greater than zero ? The same also happens for the **s** variable. The conditions to be satisfied by those fixed integers seems to be inconsistent...

Comment: *where, r,s are constants and*  just look at the line below the limit...

Comment: Now M,L are positive integers then the first condition says **r** is negative, while the last condition says **r** is positive. Only one of them can be satisfied...Probably he is making some typos.

Comment: sure there's a typo, but not sure which one :-))

Comment: btw **r** is not declared as integer (in fact it's not declared of any types so we can assume anything that fits...)

Comment: I agree on the fact that the mathematical correctness is somewhat uneven. The space between DSP and math is hard to fill :)

Comment: There were in fact many typos. I think everything is consistent now.

Comment: Well, $r$ is still a constant below the first formula :)